# to highlighting html-tags in textarea with jQuery. Possible?

Tags: jquery, html, tags, textarea, syntax-highlighting

[image: example]

I will only highlighting html-tags to red-background in textarea.

Can someone tell me easiest way to do this with jQuery ?

I have no-idea what can i do. Because we cant use HTML tags in textarea, right ? :(

Or give me some resource.

Thanks

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/RbLrK/

Comment: You need some elements for wrapping the chars and then you can style them, but it's not possible in textarea.

Comment: Now i got one : http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/ will test this

Comment: That's a hacky solution, good, it uses DIV tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to achieve the required level of control over html tags in a regular textarea. Tags are treated simply like a text, and you cannot highlight part of the text.

Try something more sophisticated like for example [CODEMIRROR](http://codemirror.net/) or [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about)